# Why is it important not to put computation-intensive code in default execution content, even within the blocking clause?

Tags: scala, playframework

When I do something computation-intensive synchronously in the default execution context, I am told I am locking a thread from Play's rendering thread pool, which may lead to thread starvation.

At the same time, I am told that

```
blocking {
    doSomethingComputationIntensive
}
```

will notify Play that this thread is blocking, which will prompt it to allocate threads more efficiently.

What does it mean in practice? My expectation would be that it would temporarily create new rendering threads if enough existing threads are blocked, thus eliminating the need to a go through the hassle of a separate execution context. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

With default EC and enough simultaneous requests, your code allows computation intensive jobs to take over whole thread pool, which is usually `>=` number of cores you have. `blocking` tells the thread pool to allocate more threads, which leave even less CPU time for any other tasks.

On a server side you likely to want the total opposite: limit the # of threads doing CPU-intensive work so that less demanding tasks (your other clients) can still be processed in parallel.

Comment: I suppose if some of your controllers rely on computation-intensive stuff and others don't, that improves the performance of those who don't. With all controllers being equally computation-intensive, it makes no difference, right?